# C# pop up string box

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

so I'm trying to make a simple pop-up box in which you can insert multiple different inputs
(first name, last name, etc...) info and it will be saved as a string. I tried using built-in text boxes but was unable to understand how it really works. Is there an easier way of doing so?
I'm using win forms if that's relevant.

Comment: You could create a derived class from Form, that has only one textbox field to get input. The container form(parent) can show your custom form as a 'Modal' to get user input.

Comment: can you share your code ? If you support what you want to do with a picture, I can help.

Comment: should look like this:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/457510081794146304/947182463497691136/unknown.png

Comment: "saved as a string" All inputs returned as one string, maybe separated by commas? Or each item is available separately via properties of the form? Written to a database? Be more specific....

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense to simply return a string, instead consider creating a class to represent your data and override ToString as per below to have the option to have a string representation of the data or to have properties for each element to collect.

You need to create a form (in this case UserInputForm), place labels and controls on the form to collect input. Validation may be done in this form or by the calling form.

Simple example, we want first, last name and birth date, add text boxes for first and last name and a DateTimePicker for birth date. A submit/ok button and a cancel button. For the Cancel button set DialogResult to Cancel in the property window.

Create a class to represent the data to be collected e.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

In the form to collect data. Note form level variable for returning data of type `Person` which the calling form uses if the sumbit button is pressed.

```
public partial class UserInputForm : Form
{
    public readonly Person Person = new Person();
    public UserInputForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
        Person.LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
        Person.BirthDate = BirthDateTimePicker.Value;
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

In the form to call the above form

```
private void GetPersonDetailsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserInputForm f = new UserInputForm();
    try
    {
        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{f.Person.FirstName} {f.Person.LastName} {f.Person.BirthDate:d}");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        f.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Then there is validation which can be done in the submit button event or in the calling form.

Simple example for in form validation.

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstNameTextBox.Text) & !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastNameTextBox.Text) & BirthDateTimePicker.Value < DateTime.Now)
    {
        Person.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
        Person.LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
        Person.BirthDate = BirthDateTimePicker.Value;
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    else
    {
        // present user with a dialog to correct input
    }

}
```

And if you really want a string alter the last to override ToString

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName},{LastName},{BirthDate:d}";
}
```

Usage

```
if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show(f.Person.ToString());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
}
```

[Full source](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version3/InputDialogSpecific)